# maximum storage allocated for date in bytes in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have searched for this but found nothing even relevant to answer my question. My doubt is like we know that max size for a varchar2 data type is 32767 bytes so on similar lines how much space is allocated to store a value of date data type. Is it treated like the varchar2 data type? such that the size will depend on number of characters? or is it something different.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CNCPT413):

> The database stores dates internally as numbers. Dates are stored in fixed-length fields of 7 bytes each, corresponding to century, year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.

So a date is always 7 bytes. Timestamps are longer (11 bytes) to hold the additional precision, and adding time zone increases that further (to 13 bytes). You can see that if you `dump` a value:

```
create table t42 (d date, t timestamp);
insert into t42 (d, t) values (sysdate, systimestamp);

column dumpd format a40
column dumpt format a60
select dump(d) as dumpd, dump(t)  as dumpt
from t42;

DUMPD                                    DUMPT                                                      
---------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,114,3,21,12,30,11      Typ=180 Len=11: 120,114,3,21,12,30,11,17,32,145,56
```

Comment: thanks for the details. Also I got to learn a new function DUMP which was not known to me before.